# how can get take data from geoserver without data loss

Tags: java, geoserver

i get take data from geoserver. but data loss be with a reason. ı dont understant why do it. for example i have 100mb jpeg in my computer disk. i load this jpeg to geoserver. then i want to get take bytes from geoserver  through java. in return bytes is data loss. method is below.

sorry for bad english. ı will grove up

```
   private static byte[] urltoBytes(String urlParameter) throws IOException
{
URL url=new URL(urlParameter);
InputStream in=new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out=new ByteArrayOutPutStream();
byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
int n=0;

while(-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
{
out.write(buf,0,n);
}
out.close();
in.close();
byte[] response=out.toByteArray();
return response;
}
```

Comment: what sort of request are you making? WMS or WCS?

Comment: request of wms. i loaded envi hdr (.hyspex) format in geoserver. i want to get take this data with data loss. @iant